# Redirecting the output of a command related to another command

Tags: time, alignment, benchmarking

I want to get a .txt file showing the computer's performance of gtime command related to another command: bwa mem.
Bwa is a genome aligner tool.
Below the code I've used:
{ gtime -v bwa mem -t 4 -R @RG\tID:$FQ\tSM:$FQ\tPL:ILLUMINA\tLB:$FQ -o 03.align/$FQ.align.sam $REF 02.trim/$FQ.R1.trim.fq.gz 02.trim/$FQ.R2.trim.fq.gz ; }  > 03.align/$FQ.BWA_MEM.txt

I rightly get the sam file (18 GBytes) but an empty txt file; I'm sure there is a syntax error.
I've tried without curly brackets or to change the position of txt file output but the same results.

Some suggestions?
Thanks in advance,
FS